# how to add a total column to a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sum my column named target where measured_component is equal to a specific condition and add it to my table but am having trouble. Ultimately I want to add 4 new rows for the 4 conditions to my current table with all the columns null except for the time_value which would be the month for each total based on the condition.

I am using the below query.

```
select sum(TARGET) as TARGET_TOTAL
from REF_targets
where MEASURED_COMPONENT ='dispatch' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT='acknoweledge' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT= 'DRIVE' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT= 'ENROUTE'
group by TIME_VALUE
```

When I have the conditions grouped, I get a crazy number for my sum, but if I create separate queries I get the correct total.

```
select time_value
     , sum(TARGET) as TARGET_TOTAL
from REF_targets
where MEASURED_COMPONENT ='dispatch' 
group by TIME_VALUE
```

**I cant select all with this query because I keep getting an error saying that I need to add ALL the columns to the group by which ultimately gives me a mirror of the data I already have for target just in a new column.**

Please help,

Thanks!

Comment: always use tags to show the version of software your are using.

Comment: Seems like you want to put your MEASURED_COMPONENT as a group by of a "partition by" windowing function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a large number because you don't put MEASURED_COMPONENT in the `GROUP BY`.  This should give you sum for each MEASURED_COMPONENT.

```
select TIME_VALUES, MEASURED_COMPONENT, sum(TARGET) as TARGET_TOTAL
from REF_targets
where MEASURED_COMPONENT ='dispatch' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT='acknoweledge' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT= 'DRIVE' 
    or MEASURED_COMPONENT= 'ENROUTE'
group by TIME_VALUES, MEASURED_COMPONENT
```